# VScode not recognizing boolean?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, boolean

I'm writing some C code in VS Code. The code includes a line that looks like this:

```c
bool func() {return true;}
```

VS Code will underline `bool` and `true`, saying identifier is undefined.

Why is VS Code reporting that it is undefined?

Comment: bool and true don't exist in C, only in C++. Or you can include <stdbool.h>

Answer (score 4):

`bool` is not a type in C.

C99 (and later) has `_Bool`. `bool` is an alias for `_Bool`.

To resolve your issue, at the top of your C code, add : `#include <stdbool.h>` - which also defines the `true` and `false` constants

ref [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/stdbool.h) for an example usage